# Using variable as class name and editing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I'm trying to simulate an Etch-a-Sketch and I want to let the user change the squares color using the **[type=color]** input. Until now I was only painting them black...

I've tried assigning a variable to the color hex code obtained from the form and creating unique classes using that value as class name, which seems ok, but then I cannot edit the css "background-value" for that class, since from what I've read, you can't edit variables' css.

Any help is appreciated.

The hover-color-applying `javascript` part is as follows:

```
//apply hover effect
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".gridSlot", function() {
        var color = document.getElementById("myColor").value; //myColor = input
        $(this).addClass(color); //what I want to do
        $(this).addClass("color"); //what I'm doing
    });
```

`.color` is a class with a fixed background-color, and if I change it by using `$(".color").css("background-color")`, it'll change both old and new squares colors.

Is there a way to let the already hovered ones be, for example, black, and draw new red ones?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0g3c6c0v/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use .css Reference [jQuery.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)
Add a non existing class name to it to check if the square is already painted.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".gridSlot", function() {

    var color = document.getElementById("myColor").value;

    if(!$(this).hasClass("painted")){

      $(this).css("background-color",color);
      $(this).addClass("painted");

    }

});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/00uk9jjt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good place to use a global variable.  At the top of your JS add line like this: `window.color_picker = "#000000";`

And then in your function simply use: `$(this).css("background-color",window.color_picker);`

Anytime that the color picker changes you'll need a js function that updates that global:
`$('#myColor').on("change", function() {
        window.color_picker = $('#myColor').val();
    });`